# Does a join table or associated table need a primary key?

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I'm pretty new at this,

I have 3 tables, one is table1, table2, and table12.
table1 has a PK table1_id and table2 has table2_id as a PK.
table12 has 3 attributes, FK table1_id, FK table2_id, and table12_name.

Is it wrong that I don't have a table12_id?

Thanks and sorry for the dumb post...

Comment: Short answer is yes. Even if that key by itself doesn't serve any purpose for linking your data model, every table *should* have a PK. In MySQL's case (InnoDB really), a table that doesn't have a PK defined gets a "hidden" one created internally - there are reasons for that, and they go beyond the scope of this question. While it's not wrong to omit a PK, you really should create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably *should* have an explicit primary key on `table12`.  The question is, which of these makes a better primary key:

- An artificial auto-incremented primary key, say `Table12Id`.
- The pair (`table1_id`, `table2_id`)

Note that the second of these imposes a uniqueness constraint on the pair, which you probably want (if you allow duplicates, then you should definitely have an explicit id).

I am someone who strongly advocates using numeric, auto-incremented primary keys on all tables.  However, for a junction table either method is fine.  There is logic to this reasoning.  All tables that represent entities should have unique keys.  This table is an implementation of a relationship, so the composite primary key makes sense.

Note that depending on how you use the table, you might still want indexes on either or both of the components of foreign key columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily wrong.

You should use a primary key, if you want to reference a specific row in a table.

The primary key must be a unique value identifying the row.

Sometimes you do not need a primary key, as in your case,
where the table12 seems to be a table that connects the other two
and names that connection.

You might want to make the connection unique (the pair of ID values in table12).

Answer (score 0):

Following the structures of your 3 tables, it is clear you had a ManyToMany relationship between `table1` and `table2`, so that is why you created an associative third table `table12`.

Actually it is just great what you did: `table12` will have a primary key which is combined of `table2_id` and `table1_id` whereas `table12_name` is optional and depends on your needs.

So to answer your question directly: you already have `table12_id` which is the combination of `table1_id` and `table2_id` that **must** be, in combination -optionally with `table12_name`- a primary key of `table12`.

Comment: the table12_name is an access_date that stores the date of access of a user_id from table1 and the directory/path_id as the other fk of table12... :)